# Decimal-based Complex struct; A good idea?

Tags: .net, floating-point-precision

I have a hankering to go home tonight and bodge up a Mandelbrot/Julia fractal generator. It's a project I've undertaken before in C++, but this time I'll give it a whirl in C# so I can more easily make it a WinForms app, use multithreading to generate the images, etc.

One thing, however, that I considered using but which looks like it might end up a crutch is the built-in Complex struct. At first glance, looks great; all the operations I'd need built in to one struct. But, a closer look shows that the struct uses doubles. Doubles only have 15-16 sig figs; their power is their range. I'm interested solely in the range of (-2,-2) to (2,2) on the complex plane, so range doesn't interest me; precision does. Decimals have 28 significant digits.

Hence the question; what's the way to go here?

1. Use the built-in Complex type; it's just a side project after all.
2. Roll my own DecimalComplex type using decimals instead of doubles. Seems a good "middle road"; the math I'd need is not difficult (multiply and add) and it'll nearly double the available precision.
3. Go for broke; implement a BigDecimal, leveraging BigInteger and tracking the decimal place myself, and use that for an UberComplex struct. IIRC the last time I messed with this, I used a similar idea but with unsigned 64-bit longs, and that got me to a zoom level where if the entire set were to be plotted at 360dpi, it would require a surface roughly the area of the solar system. I could probably do even better than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your first time writing a Mandelbrot generator, I'd recommend using the `Complex` type. Premature optimization is the root of all evil; and also, half the coolness of Mandelbrot is how you can generate an amazing image in just a few lines of code. Spending two hours implementing your own `BigDecimal` kind of defeats that purpose.

However, there's another option that I don't think you mentioned: instead of IEEE floating-point, use *fixed-point* math. Fixed-point arithmetic is really convenient for Mandelbrot generation, because addition is exactly the same, and multiplication is almost the same: `(x * y)` becomes `(x * y) >> MANTISSABITS`.

Spoiler alert! Here's a fixed-point Mandelbrot generator I wrote several years ago. It uses 28 bits after the decimal point. If your toolchain supports `int128_t`, or if you don't mind dropping into assembly, or if you don't mind doing multiplication the long way, you can trivially replace `int32_t` with `int64_t` and get 60-bit resolution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "ImageFmtc.h"

/* Represent each component of the complex number
 * as a fixed-point value between -4 and +4. There
 * are 4 bits before the binary point and 28 bits after. */
typedef int32_t REALFIXED;
typedef int32_t IMAGFIXED;

#define MandelWidth   300
#define MandelHeight  300

unsigned char Image[MandelWidth][MandelHeight];


void mandelbrot(REALFIXED centerx, IMAGFIXED centery, REALFIXED windowsize)
{
    int x, y;
    unsigned char *image_ptr = &Image[0][0];

    for (y = 0; y < MandelHeight; ++y) {

    const IMAGFIXED z_imag = (1LL * windowsize * y / MandelHeight) + centery;

    for (x = 0; x < MandelWidth; ++x) {

        const REALFIXED z_real = (1LL * windowsize * x / MandelWidth) + centerx;

        REALFIXED t_real = z_real;
        IMAGFIXED t_imag = z_imag;

        int iter;

        for (iter=0; iter < 255; ++iter) {
        long long r2 = (1uLL * t_real * t_real) >> 28;
        long long i2 = (1uLL * t_imag * t_imag) >> 28;
        long long two_ri = (1uLL * t_real * t_imag) >> 27;
        if (r2 + i2 > (4LL << 28))
            break;
        t_real = (r2 - i2) + z_real;
        t_imag = (two_ri) + z_imag;
        }

        *image_ptr++ = iter & 0xFF;
    }
    }
    return;
}

REALFIXED double2fixed(double x)
{
    return (REALFIXED)(x * (1uLL << 28));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double cx, cy, scale;
    sscanf(argv[1], "%lf", &cx);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%lf", &cy);
    sscanf(argv[3], "%lf", &scale);
    mandelbrot(double2fixed(cx-scale/2), double2fixed(cy-scale/2), double2fixed(scale));
    WritePGM5("mandel.pgm", (unsigned char *)Image, MandelWidth, MandelHeight);
    return 0;
}
```

Re the size of the solar system: Even though your *numbers* may have a resolution of 60 bits, that doesn't mean that you can actually compute a pixel-accurate *rendering of the Mandelbrot set* at 60-bit resolution. Rounding errors on the multiplications mean that as you zoom in, your image will turn all bloopy and fuzzy much faster than you expect. I'm sure someone has done the math, but I don't know it off the top of my head. Keyword "error propagation".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This isn't my first crack at a Mandelbrot generator; I've created one successfully two separate times in C++ as I said, this is just my first try in C# and as a WinForms app.

Comment: Definitely look into fixed-point math with plain old integer types, then.